# Find the smallest possible value of the sum $x_1+x_2+...+x_{2008}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

Let $x_1, x_2,...,x_{2008}$ are numbers such that $|x_1|=999$ and for all  $n=2,...,2008$
$$|x_n|=|x_{n-1}+1|$$
Find the smallest possible value of the sum
$$x_1+x_2+...+x_{2008}$$

#### My work:

Let $S=x_1+x_2+...+x_{2008}$.

If $x_1=-999, x_2=-998, ..., -1,0,-1,0$
then I think the answer $-500004$.

But I don't know how to prove that:

Comment: Finding the smallest possible value of $|x_1+x_2+\cdots+x_{2008}|$ is also an interesting problem. (In fact, it's how I interpreted the problem on first reading.)

Comment: The minimization problem can be understood as a multi-staging process in which the transition to a new staging, from $\sum_{k=1}^N x_k$ to $\sum_{k=1}^{N+1} x_k$ is constrained by the condition $ |x_{k+1}| = |x_k+1|$ so the procedure to solve it can be successfully handled with a Dynamic Programming algorithm.

Comment: On a side note, @Roman, let me ask you this: aren't you going to create an OEIS entry for the sequence from https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2469058/a-n-is-the-smallest-positive-integer-number-such-that-sqrta-n-sqrta-n-1? IMHO, it more than deserves one.

Comment: @IvanNeretin: No! I do not know how do it. But if you want you will can do it.

Comment: @Roman So I will. May I know your full name, at least? I don't want to claim it in my name, as the idea is yours.

Comment: It is perfectly OK if you prefer to go anonymous, though.

Comment: @Ivan Neretin: I think that the author of this problem is EdwardTurJ

Comment: @Roman Great. Now what's _his_ full name? You see, they don't use nicknames there at OEIS.

Comment: @IvanNeretin: His name is Edward Turkevich

Comment: @Roman Got it, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint.

Calling

$$
S_1(x_1) = \{-m,m\}
$$

and

$$
S_k(x_k) = \min_{x_k}\left(S_{k-1}(x_{k-1})+x_k\right)\ \ \mbox{s. t. }\ \ |x_k|=|x_{k-1}+1|
$$

we have after $N$ steps the sought min as $\min S_N(x_N)$